# LESS - How to select a deeply nested element by class name?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, less

I am using a CSS library that relies on Less. In order to override the CSS properties of a certain element I am trying to use the higher degree of specificity technique by wrapping a parent element "commentPaddingFix" as so:

```
<div class='commentPaddingFix'>
  <div class='Child1'>
     <div class='Child2'>
       <div class='ant-comment-inner'>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the Less file:

```
.commentPaddingFix {
  .ant-comment-inner {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

I need a solution that works when you know the className of the element you are targeting for any arbitrary number of nested parent elements. I can't use nth child technique as the children numbers vary from render to render.

Comment: It’s kind of a dumb hack, but you can increase specificity by repeating the same selector: `.commentPaddingFix.commentPaddingFix.commentPaddingFix { ... }`

Comment: What’s wrong with your Less example? Why not just `.commentPaddingFix .ant-comment-inner { ... }`?

Comment: It doesn't override the CSS properties of the .ant-comment-inner.

Comment: If you inspect the element in dev tools do you see your rules, they’re just not specific enough? If so, try repeating the outer selector like in my comment above.

Comment: The rules actually don't appear at all

Comment: I tried the hack you mentioned to no avail

Comment: Are your class names correct and visible in the output markup?

Comment: Yes, I have successfully applied a style to the commentPaddingFix element, and the ant-comment-inner is definately correct.

Comment: If it makes any difference, I am using react and importing the style like className={styles.commentPaddingFix}

Comment: are you using css modules? are your class names showing up in the dom unmodified?

Comment: Hi yes I am, my class gets a random name. I can currently get to the classname I want to target only with the nth child method/

Comment: Have you considered using [:global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065474/636077) to leave the classnames unmodified?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Less but if that works anything like Sass your solution should work.

Here's what it looks like with pure css: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-bhaskara-3781k.

Comment: Why did you bother.