# How to implement react-dates css in css-modules?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, css-modules, react-dates

so react-dates css worked fine until i moved to css-modules. i tried importing the css file from node modules in index.js files and in the head of the html file but none of them worked.
Any help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is working perfectly for this problem

> In `webpack.config.js` define a function which checks your file to
> decide if it's **css module** or **global**; done using getLocalIdent
> option.
>
> This is the method that I'm currently using in my setup.
>
> This also **requires** your files to have some naming convention,
> [name].module.css for css modules and [name].css for regular files.
> See example below:

```js
// regex to test for modules, loaderUtils is part of webpack dependencies
const cssModuleRegex = new RegExp(/\.module\.(less|css)$/);
const loaderUtils = require("loader-utils");

// inside webpack rules
      {
        test: /\.(less|css)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: CssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: { hot: is_dev, reloadAll: is_dev }
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: { 
                modules: { 
                    localIdentName: '[local]___[hash:base64:5]', 
                    getLocalIdent: getLocalIdent
                }
            }
          },
          "postcss-loader",
          "less-loader"
        ]
      }

// this is a copy of the default function, modified slightly to achieve our goal
function getLocalIdent(loaderContext, localIdentName, localName, options) {

    // return local name if it's a global css file
    if (!cssModuleRegex.test(loaderContext.resourcePath)) {
        return localName;
    }

    if (!options.context) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      options.context = loaderContext.rootContext;
    }

    const request = path
      .relative(options.context, loaderContext.resourcePath)
      .replace(/\\/g, '/');

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    options.content = `${options.hashPrefix + request}+${localName}`;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    localIdentName = localIdentName.replace(/\[local\]/gi, localName);

    const hash = loaderUtils.interpolateName(
      loaderContext,
      localIdentName,
      options
    );

    return hash
      .replace(new RegExp('[^a-zA-Z0-9\\-_\u00A0-\uFFFF]', 'g'), '-')
      .replace(/^((-?[0-9])|--)/, '_$1');
  }
```

Source: [How to apply global styles with CSS modules in a react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39805537/how-to-apply-global-styles-with-css-modules-in-a-react-app)