# React DataTable customization

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-data-table-component

Is it possible to style the headers of the `react-data-table-component`? I tried this

```
  columns: [
    {
      name: "Name",
      selector: "name",
      sortable: true,
      style: {
        background: "orange",
      },
    },
  ],
```

But it styles all the cells underneath that header, not the header itself.
[image]

Please let me know if there is documentation that I study this component API from.

Comment: add a minimal example with code.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't find any mechanism to customize only the header cells, but you could style them with CSS selectors by passing an `id` in each column object and using the [rdt_TableCol](https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/v7.1.0/src/DataTable/TableCol.tsx#L189) class

```
  columns: [
    {
      name: "Name",
      selector: "name",
      id: "name",
      sortable: true,
      style: {
        background: "orange",
      },
    },
  ],
```

and in a CSS file

```
[data-column-id="name"].rdt_TableCol {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/style-header-cell-rdt-c1y35

of course, this method is susceptible to internal changes in the lib, make sure to fix the version and revisit the code if you upgrade the version

Comment: That's a Great Idea Thank you so much!

Comment: Can this work with CSS modules? if it would what would the syntax to it be?

Comment: @MahmoudMuhammed just importing the css file should work https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065474/1868008

Comment: It worked! 
Thank you so much ❤️

Answer (score 3):

In the DataTable props you can assign a style to the customStyles property like so:

```
import { tableCustomStyles } from './tableStyle.jsx';
            
<DataTable
   customStyles={tableCustomStyles}
/>
```

And then in the tableStyle.jsx file you can customize all properties of the table like this:

```
const tableCustomStyles = {
  headCells: {
    style: {
      fontSize: '20px',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      paddingLeft: '0 8px',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#FFA500'
    },
  },
}
export { tableCustomStyles };
```

Here is the API reference: https://react-data-table-component.netlify.app/?path=/docs/api-custom-styles--page

And here is the styles.ts file from the repo that shows some of the properties you can manipulate: https://github.com/jbetancur/react-data-table-component/blob/master/src/DataTable/styles.ts

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it's coming from the API documentation and is the pattern they call for.