# How to reference a generic class name inside a module.scss file

Tags: sass, module, less

I am using `module.scss` in `next.js` for styling.

```js
import styles from './test.module.scss';

export default function Test() {
  return (
    <>
          <div className={styles.wrapper}></div>
          <div className="aaaa">asdsa</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```css
// test.module.scss


.wrapper {
}


.aaaa {
  background-color: red;
} // It's not working!!!
```

The class `aaaa` is applied as a generic variable. How can I style it while referencing the generic class name inside the test.module.scss file?

I want to style while referencing that class name without using child selectors!

Comment: You can use `:global(.aaaa)`.
Please, also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065474/15321956)

Comment: What do you mean with generic classname? do you mean the name is provided during runtime as a dynamic parameter? the question is currently unclear.